# How to generate random number to input form group index on angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Dynamic form input where the user can press a button to add more input fields that will be bound to the template with ngFor like this:

```
*ngFor="let data of getTasks(myFormdata); let i=index"
```

and the ts file

```
getTasks(myFormdata) {
    return myFormdata.get('inputs').controls
  }
```

All this works great. The user can add new input fields, but I have a button that will generate a random number and set the random number to the input value. Since I am new to Angular 2, I can't seem to make it happen when there is more than one input field. The method to generate the random number into the field is the following:

```
getRandomNumber() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000)) + 100000;
    const control = <FormArray>this.myFormdata.controls['inputs'];
    control.setValue([{numbers: random, pari: 25}])
}
```

What is missing from my `getRandomNumber()` method to make it generate a random number for each added field?

Answer (score 6):

I got the solution... the following is my solution

```
  getRandomNumber(i: number) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000)) + 100000;
    const control = <FormArray>this.myFormdata.controls['inputs'];
    const random = this._fb.group({numbers: +quickpicked, pari: 25});
    control.setControl(i, random)


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'codegenerator';
  date = new Date();
  codeGenerated = '';
  evtMsg: any;
  randomString() {
 const chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
 const stringLength = 10;
 let randomstring = '';
 for (let i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
 const rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
 randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
}
 this.codeGenerated = randomstring;
 return 0;
}
}
```

```html
  <div class="card text-center" style="width: 40rem;">
      <div class="card-head">
        <button (click)="randomString()" class="d-inline bg-primary btn-lg text-white">Generate code</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="display-2 text-dark">{{codeGenerated}}</h1>
      </div>
      </div>
```

[Github source with angular 8](https://github.com/JohannThapa/codegenerator)